# как расширить пусто div без контента c шириной max-width

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток!

1. Имеется DIV с шириной max-width (700px/но это не так важно).
2. В этом DIV есть изображение, но с позиционированием absolute. Поэтому оно не может расширить родительский DIV до его максимальной ширины.
3. Блок должен сужаться при изменении ширины viewport (резиниться)

Вопрос: чем расширить DIV до его максимальной ширины? Возможно есть специально свойство? Я мог заполнить его текстом-рыбой. Его все ровно не будет видно под absolute картинкой. НО засорять html документ нет желания.

Ширина в процентах не походит. И фиксированная ширина тоже. Нужен именно max-width. Для резиновой верстки. То есть, чтобы при сужении viewport, блок мог сужаться.

Comment: добавьте min-width: 700px

Comment: изображение по высоте будет меняться или нет?

Comment: min-width не подходит, так как необходимо, чтобы блок сужался при изменении ширины viewport (резинился)

изображение по высоте будет меняться, но только по медиазапросам

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в css добавить padding для div элемента

```
<div style="padding-left: 100px; padding-right: 100px;">
    <img src="путь">
</div>
```

Comment: Вариант походящий. Но тогда DIV не сужается при изменении ширины viewport. Необходимо, чтобы блок резинился.

Comment: тогда надо это добавить в css, и через @media изменять

Answer (score 0):

Дамы и господа, я нашел ответ на свой же вопрос!

1. Назначаем родительскому блоку display: flex
2. DIV с шириной max-width: 700px становится flex-элементом
3. Ему же назначаем свойство flex-grow: 1, что позволяет ему расширяться

Та-дам!